# Branch.io - Android : InitSessionWithData return empty response when launch app

Tags: android, titanium, branch.io

I am integrating titanium branch.io module with enterprise client project. I used OneSignal for push notification. When push notification received, OneSignal module launch app and fire event "getNotificationData". From this event I fired branch.initSessionWithData("Branch-URL");

This issue only in Android. iOS I have managed with handlePushNotification() method.

Most of the time I got "{}" response and I not able navigate particular page. but when I force kill the app and launch again, Now got response from branch and Navigate to particular page.

```
(KrollRuntimeThread) [2076,5122] start init with data =http://links.shukranrewards.com/shuk-enrollment
(KrollRuntimeThread) [2,5124] Uri is http://links.shukranrewards.com/shuk-enrollment
(KrollRuntimeThread) [11,5135] inside onInitFinished
(KrollRuntimeThread) [0,5135] return is not null
(KrollRuntimeThread) [0,5135] {}
(KrollRuntimeThread) [0,5135] start createSessionDict
(KrollRuntimeThread) [0,5135] data: 
(KrollRuntimeThread) [1,5136] {}
(KrollRuntimeThread) [0,5136] start parseJSONObject
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alex from Branch.io here: unfortunately, we haven't added support for push notifications through Titanium yet. However, since you figured out how to do it with iOS, we also support the same mechanism with the core Android SDK. Please see [this document for an example](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/android-branch-deep-linking#deeplink-via-push-notification).

I hope you can get this working for your client. It'll be a while before we add support on Titanium most likely.

Comment: I will try to make it work by modify official branch.io module. Thanks for the response.